# How can I remove residue left by shower door tracks?

Tags: shower, bathtub, adhesive

I removed the base track for the shower doors and one side (one side was already removed) from a cheap shower (not ceramic) in my apartment. I got a caulk removal tool and have been using a dissolver spray but am having no luck getting the harder bits off that were adhering the tracks to the tub. Does anyone have advice for removing and cleaning something like this up?

Comment: Are you sure it's caulk you're trying to remove? It could be construction adhesive. What is "dissolver spray"? What kind of "caulk removal tool" are you using? Pictures of the situation may help others determine what you're looking at if you're not 100% sure.